# Terraform Variable format for path and null values

Tags: terraform

I am trying to convert the below table field into a variable. I am unsure what type of variable definition to use for schema path and null values.

Please can someone help with variable definition for this sample tables value.

```
tables = [
  {
   table_id = "test"
   friendly_name = "testfriend"
   schema = file("${path.root}/schema/schema.json")
   labels = {}
   time_partitioning = {
     type = "Day"
     field = null
     expiration_ms =null
   }
   range_partitioning = null
   expiration_time = null
   clustering = []
  }


]
```

Comment: The `null` values can remain as is. The `schema` could probably be `map(any)`, unless you know all the types which are used inside the JSON file.

Comment: Please can you help me with complete variable definition . I am new to terrafrom .

Comment: If the value for `schema` will always be a JSON format string, then that would be `string` (unless you were to attempt to convert it as @MarkoE states). You need API documentation for all of the `null` since they are optional in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Terraform does not have a data type specifically for filesystem paths, so those would need to just be `string` where the string contains a filename. Since your current example includes a call to the `file` function, you won't be able to replicate this data structure *exactly* as an input variable: input variables must be constant values, and cannot be based on the results of a function.

In Terraform's type system, `null` is a valid value of any type, but you will still need to decide what type those fields should have so that Terraform can ensure that any *non-null* value that's passed in will be converted to the expected type.

I can only guess what `range_partitioning`, `expiration_time`, `field`, and `expiration_ms` mean, but otherwise the following might be a reasonable type constraint for values like the one you've included in your question:

```
variable "tables" {
  list(object({
    table_id        = string
    friendly_name   = string
    schema_filename = string
    labels          = optional(map(string), {})
    time_partitioning = object({
      type          = string
      field         = optional(string)
      expiration_ms = optional(number)
    })
    range_partitioning = optional(object({
      type  = string
      field = optional(string)
      # maybe some other attributes???
    }), [])
    expiration_time = optional(string)
    clustering = optional(list(object({
      # presumably "clustering" expects objects
      # with attributes that describe how to cluster?
    })), [])
  }))
}
```

You can deal with the fact that the input variable specifies a filename rather than the file contents by doing a small transformation in a local value inside the module:

```
locals {
  tables = tolist([
    for table in var.tables :
    merge(table, {
      schema = file(table.schema_filename)
    })
  ])
}
```

This would extend each of the given objects with the additional attribute `schema` which contains the content of whatever file was specified in `schema_filename`. You can then use `local.tables` instead of `var.tables` in any situation where it's necessary to access the `schema` attribute.